# Is there a way to have information on one page automatically feed into another?

Tags: customization, pages

Specifically, I have a page that lists events that happen each week on Tuesdays and Saturdays. I want these events, posted to this page, to then go onto two separate pages - one just showing the events on a Tuesday, and the other events on a Saturday. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add some more detail about how the events are stored and any code you're using right now that's relevant, you're much more likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create page templates inside your theme and create page-{template-name}.php for each one of them and you need to code the appropriate query for each case.

Then go to each page inside admin panel, open each page and just assign each page to their matching template.

If you are not familiar with how to do any of the above, provide the code of your current page and I can give you feedback code on that.

Answer (score -1):

I have an idea!

First, put the one copy of the list you want to edit into a widget with a text element.

Second, place the widget on your page using a `shortcode` and this free plugin: [Widgets on Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widgets-on-pages/)

Now, the same list appears on your site wherever the `shortcode` is placed!